# jquery change radio value from div input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to divide a number in 3 different numbers after that I need to give that value to the radio button. this is the code I have. I have the script to capture the value from the radio button but not to change it.

```
   //Radio And Div
     <input type="radio" name=presets class="m" value="">
       <div id="choice_month" class="m"></div>
     <input type="radio" name=presets class="q" value="">
       <div id="choice_quart" class="q"></div>
     <input type="radio" name=presets class="y" value="">
       <div id="choice_year" class="y"></div>
```

JQuery for division:

```
    $("#p").click(function() {
     var num1 = $("input[id='amount']").val(),
     num2 = $("input[id='m']").val(),
     result = parseFloat(num1, 10) / parseFloat(num2, 10);
 mm = result.toFixed(2);
    $(".m").text(mm);//Do stuff when the button is clicked.
     var num3 = $("input[id='amount']").val(),
     num4 = $("input[id='q']").val(),
     result = parseFloat(num3, 10) / parseFloat(num4, 10);
     mm = result.toFixed(2);
    $(".q").text(mm);
     var num5 = $("input[id='amount']").val(),
     num6 = $("input[id='y']").val(),
     result = parseFloat(num5, 10) / parseFloat(num6, 10);
    mm = result.toFixed(2);
    $(".y").text(mm);
      });
```

Comment: ID's should be unique, and preferably not numbers. Also, your jQuery isn't actually using any of the ID's/Classes used in your HTML...

Comment: You can't have spaces in your IDs either ;)

Comment: Can you make a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) for us?

Comment: ..and your input `names` need quotations around the value... not mandatory but considered good practice.

Comment: Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/6Zby4/

Comment: When I press the radiobutton The text below need to change to the amount in the div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a bit lost in your code so made [this DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LZ5Uz/4/). It's unstyled but does what you're asking.

```
$("#button").click(function() {
    $("#amount").trigger("change");
});

$("#amount").change(function() {
    var num1 = $("input[id='amount']").val(),
         num2 = $("input[id='m']").val(),
         num3 = $("input[id='q']").val(),
         num4 = $("input[id='y']").val(),
         result = 0;

    result = parseFloat(num1, 10) / parseFloat(num2, 10);
    $("#choice_m").text(result.toFixed(2));

    result = parseFloat(num1, 10) / parseFloat(num3, 10);
    $("#choice_q").text(result.toFixed(2));

    result = parseFloat(num1, 10) / parseFloat(num4, 10);
    $("#choice_y").text(result.toFixed(2));

    $("input[name='presets']:first").trigger("change");//trigger our on-change event in case the radio has been selected BEFORE the button was clicked.
});

$("input[name='presets']").change(function() {
    var id = "#choice_"+$("input[name='presets']:checked").attr("id"); 
    $("#result").val($(id).text());
})
```

Comment: So clean.!! I was trying to mix another extra code I have.

Answer (score 0):

Please alter the class with id, since this way of HTML is not legal (using same id for different elements)

```
<input type="radio" name="presets" class="m" value="">
```

Your div is as:

```
<div id="choice_month" class="m"></div>
```

Try this:

```
$('div').click(function () {
   $('input[type=radio]').attr('value', $(this).attr('class'));
}
```

This will get the ID of the `div` when you click on it, and then add that to the value of the radio button.

Comment: I don't understand this answer.

Comment: I need to transfer the class="m" value to the radio value.

Comment: You can see in the code, the class of the `div` that was clicked on is passed to the `value` of the `radio` button through a parameter. It just changes the attribute values of the elements. It should work..